# jogl - first person camera

Tags: opengl, jogl

Im trying make first person camera in my project. I followed this tutorial

http://www.morrowland.com/apron/tutorials/gl/gl_camera_3b.zip

Keyboard movement is ok but Mouse movement is strange. I'm using java+jolg but i think there is no much difference

Here is the two methods responsible for rotating:

```
    public void rotate(float speed) {
    aux = mView.minus(mPos);
    mView.z = (float) (mPos.z + Math.sin(Math.toRadians(speed)) * aux.x + Math.cos(Math.toRadians(speed))
            * aux.z);
    mView.x = (float) (mPos.x + Math.cos(Math.toRadians(speed)) * aux.x - Math.sin(Math.toRadians(speed))
            * aux.z);

}

    public void mouseMove(float x, float y) {
    float angle_y = 0.0f;
    float angle_z = 0.0f;

    if ((x == w/2) && (h/2 == y))
        return;

    robot.mouseMove(w / 2, h / 2);


    angle_y = (float) ((w / 2 - x)) / 1000;
    angle_z = (float) ((h / 2 - y)) / 1000;


    mView.y += angle_z * 2;

    if ((mView.y - mPos.y) > 8)
        mView.y = mPos.y + 8;
    if ((mView.y - mPos.y) < -8)
        mView.y = mPos.y - 8;

    rotate(-angle_y); // Rotate
}
```

and there is listener:

```
            public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
            Point p = e.getPoint();
            camera.mouseMove((float)p.getX(),(float) p.getY());
        }
```

Comment: Please expand a little on "is strange".  Please give more details on the issue(s)

Comment: Camera looking is not working right. Move its not same for all direction and its very choppy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem was in how java getting point from canvas.  So if I changed

```
Point p = e.getPoint();
```

to

```
Point p = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation();
```

It works.

Sorry for late answer. I forgotten for this question.

Answer (score 0):

I would try putting in a timer and only updating every so often - you can overload yourself if you try to recalculate the frame every time mouse moved fires.